# Обработка исключения TimeoutException в классе WebDriverWait

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, uiautomation

Здравствуйте.
Столкнулся с проблемой, как правильно обработать выбрасываемое исключения, начал читать примеры, но именно такого, как в моём случае ни где не нашёл. Прошу оказать помощь.

Вызываю метод командой:

```
parse.openPage("http://"+ipAddresses.get(i)+"/");
```

Сам метод openPage:

```
void openPage(String sAddress){
        driver.get(sAddress);
        **waitLoadById**(30,"button");
    }
```

Метод waitLoadById:

```
void waitLoadById(int sec, String sId) {
        WebElement presenceElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, sec)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id(sId)));
    }
```

Если через 20 секунд элемент не обнаружиться, ExpectedCondition выбросит исключение TimeoutException. Где его ловить?
Пробую команду parse.openPage("http://"+ipAddresses.get(i)+"/") заключить в try-catch:

```
    try{
       parse.openPage("http://"+ipAddresses.get(i)+"/");
   //другие команды по дальнейшему парсингу
    }catch(TimeoutException te){ 
       прекратить парсинг этого ip-адреса и начать заново с новым ip
    }
```

Получается так, что срабатывает блок catch даже тогда, когда элемент обнаруживается. То есть сам WevDriverWait выбрасывает какое-то исключение, которое соответственно тоже ловится моим catch'ом?

Цель такая: если элемент обнаруживается - продолжить парсинг, если элемент не обнаружился - прервать парсинг адреса и перейти к следующему.
Я немного запутался, где размещать блоки try-cath, что ловить и т.д.?

Comment: Так поставьте в блоке catch `te.printStackTrace()` и посмотрите, в каком месте кода возникает исключение

Comment: и прикрепите к вопросу трейс

Comment: Спасибо, trace помог.

Comment: @Cenzor напишите ответ, чтобы в будущем люди знали решение

Comment: С помощью трейса посмотрел кто выбрасывает исключение, по какому стеку оно проходит. Ранее я в каждом методе явно пробрасывал исключение вниз по стеку, на этот раз я его стал ловить методом, который находится внизу цепочки вызова исключения. Вся логика отрабатывается так, как нужно.